# Priming a runtime service worker cache using Workbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

How to use below code in WorkboxSW to register routes for all per-caching urls. This per-cached urls includes ajax that will go to server also!

```
$.ajax({
   url : '/MyAPI/Records',
   type : 'GET',
   dataType:'json',
   success : function(data) {              
     alert('Records: '+data);

     //build urls array to get all records details  
     var urls = [];
     urls.push('/MyAPI/Records')
     $(data).each(function (index) {
        urls.push('/MyAPI/Records/' + data[index].id + '/data') 
      });

     //add all urls to cache
     var requests = urls.map(url => new Request(url));
     caches.open('my-cache').then(cache => {
     return cache.addAll(requests).then(() => {
        // At this point, `cache` will be populated with `Response` objects,
        // and `requests` contains the `Request` objects that were used.
     }).catch(error => console.error(`Oops! ${error}`));
  });
},
error : function(request,error)
{
    alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workbox's precaching relies on having access to a local file representing the resource at build time. This allows it to generate a hash of each resource its managing (based on the local file's contents) and then keep that cached resource up to date whenever the local file changes.

What you're suggestion sounds more like Workbox's support for handling certain routes via runtime caching. You can configure it via something like:

```
// Replace with your actual API endpoint.
const API_URL = 'https://my-api-server.com/api/restEndpoint';

// Use whichever strategy you'd prefer: networkFirst, staleWhileRevalidate, etc.
const apiCallHandler = workboxSW.strategies.networkFirst({
  cacheName: 'my-api'
});

workboxSW.registerRoute(
  API_URL,
  apiCallHandler
);
```

This will result in responses from `https://my-api-server.com` being added to the cache named `my-api` at runtime, after you make your first request. (In this particular case, using the `networkFirst` strategy, those cached responses will only be used if the network is unavailable.)

If you're not okay with the runtime cache starting out "cold" and you feel like it needs to be primed, then you could do that by writing your own `install` event handler alongside your Workbox code:

```
// Your existing WorkboxSW code goes here.

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('my-api')
      .then(cache => cache.add(API_URL))
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How can you use workboxSW.registerRoute outside of serviceworker.js file? In service worker js, I use importScripts to use workbox-sw.js library but how can you use it on other pages from where you want to do runtime caching?
My api calls are dynamic based on IDs i.e /MyAPI/Records/{xxx}/data

Comment: You execute this code in your service worker (either in a top-level service worker file, or in a standalone JS file that gets pulled in via `importScripts()`) and then you don't have to change anything in your web app's pages. Once the SW takes control of a client web app, it will automatically start intercepting network requests and handling them, without you having to change your pages.

Comment: How can you make ajax calls from the standalone JS? My api calls are dynamic means it depends on  /MyAPI/Records api to build url for /MyAPI/Records/{xxx}/data

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but in general, you can request data from an API from a JS client (either a page or the SW) using the `fetch()` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: I updated the code in my question to give you better idea! cache.addAll is fetching / caching all data after all urls are added into urls array using ajax!

Comment: Any thought with updated code? Is it good idea to move the code on stand alone js and use fetch() api instead of ajax to get ''/MyAPI/Records'' & build the urls for "'/MyAPI/Records'/xxx/Data" and fetch them all?

Comment: The way you make your HTTP requests on your client pages is up to you—you can use `fetch()` or XHR, and both will be intercepted by a properly configured SW. The SW configuration I passed along will handle caching, so you shouldn't have to end up managing the cache in the client pages.